# WKNavigation delegate functions calling too late

Tags: swift, xcode, wkwebview

I am loading two websites in two different web views and after loading website i am hiding some content of it which is working perfect using **WKNavigationDelegate**  did finish method.

but issue is did finish function is calling about 90 sec after loading website in web view.

Function is working fine but i just want to know why this function is loading too late it should execute function right after loading website.

my code is

```
web_view.navigationDelegate = self as? WKNavigationDelegate
        web_view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        self.web_view.load(request)
        self.view.addSubview(self.web_view)
```

delegate method

```
extension urdu_HomeViewController : WKNavigationDelegate{

    //enable javascript to remove vavigation from website

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {


  let removeelementid = "javascript:(function() { " + "document.getElementsByClassName('td-header-menu-wrap-full td-container-wrap')[0].style.display=\"none\"; " + "})()"
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(removeelementid) { (res, error) in
            if error != nil
            {
                print("Error")
            }
            else
            {
                //print(res!)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**WKNavigationDelegate** didFinish method is called only after **all** subresources are loaded. So in your case it might be that some resource takes too much time to load and that delays calling didFinish.

You should rather use `WKUserScript` to execute your JS right after DOM is ready.